# How to retrieve the error text from results view of error property into the text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am trying to print the error text when the runtime error is encountered in my controller function. There's is a line in my function where I am adding

```
items.Add(shell.Streams.Error.ToString());
```

But the text which is being added prints the type

```
'{System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection<System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord>}'
```

The error I am getting when I put the break point and parse the results view is

> {Cannot find an object with identity: '3180af9e-3c0e-41ff-94fe-3af'}

I have tried typecasting the error into string.

```
public List<string> PowerShellExecutorGrd(string scriptPath, string arg)
{
    var items = new List<string>();
    using (var shell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        shell.Commands.AddCommand(scriptPath).AddArgument(arg);
        var results = shell.Invoke();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(shell.HadErrors.ToString());
        if (shell.HadErrors == false) {
            if (results.Any()) {
                foreach (var psObj in results){
                    items.Add(Server.HtmlEncode(psObj.ToString().Trim('{','}')));
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                items.Add(shell.Streams.Error.ToString());
            }
        };
        return items;
    }
}
```

The error message should be

> "Cannot find an object with identity: '3180af9e-3c0e-41ff-94fe-3af'" instead of System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shell.Streams.Error` object is of type `PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>`. Since The [`PSDataCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psdatacollection-1) class does not override the `ToString()` method, that means when you call `.ToString()`, it's actually calling [`Object.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring), which just prints out the name of the type. That's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

The point is that `shell.Streams.Error` doesn't actually describe the error. It's is a *collection* of errors. So you need to traverse the collection and call `ToString()` on the `ErrorRecord` objects inside the collection.

There will likely only be one `ErrorRecord` in the collection, but just in case there are more, you could concatenate them together:

```
var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ErrorRecord err in shell.Streams.Error) {
    errorMessage.AppendLine(err.ToString());
}
items.Add(errorMessage.ToString());
```

The [`ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord) class *does* override the [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.tostring) method, so that should get you the message you expect.